# Can Flutter Web replace doing regular websites?

Tags: flutter, frontend, flutter-web

So I'm having a client that wants an online-coaching website , and I'm an flutter app developer , I've never used flutter web, and I was wondering if I can do the work in Flutter Web instead of learning Angular or Reactjs etc , because I'm familiar with flutter and it will take less time to grasp the concepts .

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**

YES, 100%, it will work very well. No need to learn anything new. Same code will also create a website.

Guidelines are [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/web)

**Exceptions:**

In case you are using packages, double-check that those are compatible with "web" (most are compatible but otherwise, you can avoid those)

**Bonus information:**

You can publish to  Firebase... It is free and very fast.

Guidelines [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/web).

Comment: And if I want to open the website from my phone, do I write seperate code and try to make it responsive or there is another way for dealing with this issue

Comment: From your phone you can do both ways. Either 1- open as an app (if you previously installed the app) , or 2- open as any other website (nothing extra to perform, just call normal URL from browser)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the Answer provided by our friend Canada2000, and would like to add that things like:

- SEO
- Page responsibility to devices
- Everything else

It is entirely a responsibility of the developer to implement and make sure it is working properly.

There's no magic solution, you just have to make sure you have made the changes that are necessary for the platforms you wish to deliver your app.

Sometimes you might need to use a couple `ifs` to change the behavior from one platform to another, so be aware that not everything will work "out of the box". Each native platform has its own specifications and requirements.